# PHP Routing - Disabling 404?

Tags: php, url, routes

I'm creating a basic routing system, so my URL's would look like this:

> www.domain.com/index.php/controller

Only problem is, when I go to that address, I get a 404. Is there any way to overwrite this with PHP (without using .htaccess)?

Comment: I have an `index.php` file. @H2CO3

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache should send the request you described to index.php by default.

Comment: Ah, silly mistake. Didn't have Apache running, works fine now! If you answer, I'll mark it as accepted. :)

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache should send the request you described to index.php by default. Maybe you forgot to start Apache webserver?

Answer (score 0):

the index.php file would need to be your bootstrap file that would load the controller depending on what's being requested to it, but without using mod rewrite the url would be something like:

```
www.domain.com/index.php?url=controller
```

Answer (score -2):

I've set up something like this before - In mine I had to have apache do redirects with mod_rewrite: mine sends www.domain.com/controller to www.domain.com/index.php?*route*=controller - should be similar to what you're after I think.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Question included: _Is there any way to overwrite this with PHP (without using .htaccess)?_

Comment: Well, it was more in httpd.conf / apache.conf but fair enough.